# Assumptions for uniform measure of SDE on manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, stochastic-processes, smooth-manifolds, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we're working on a compact, Riemannian manifold $M$. Suppose $dX_t = -b(X_t, t)\,dt + \sigma^2 \,dB_t$ is started at the uniform measure on $M$. What kind of assumptions on $b$ make it so that $X_t$ is also uniform $\forall t$?

Comment: In particular, I'm trying to work on a torus. I believe if $b = \nabla F$ and $F$ is divergence-free, the claim is true.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463199/assumptions-for-uniform-measure-of-sde-on-manifolds#comment1202506_463199), a comment like this is probably better edited into the question itself.